# iOS regex pattern not working to match numbers

Tags: ios, regex, numbers

I want to match strings of the forms:

```
123
.123
1.123
```

and I am using the following string for my regex

```
@"^\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?$"
```

However, it matches strings of the following forms as well

```
1.2.3
1..2..3
123...
```

What's wrong with my regex? I used the `^` and `$` because I don't want the string to contain anything other than the number forms mentioned.

**EDIT:**

I logged what is matched in the string like `78..7` and found that the match location is 0 and length is 0 with a result of "" being matched. Any ideas? Shouldn't the range location be NSNotFound if the length is 0? I suppose the regex expression is fine then and I can just check for !length but that seems like an unnecessary work around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?<!\.)\d*(\.\d+)?$
```

I added a negative look-behind assertion that means that no dot is allowed before that numbers. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I want to match strings of the form .123 as well though. I'm using http://regexpal.com/ to check my regex and my pattern should work correctly. I'm not sure why it doesn't work in xcode.

Comment: Okay I missed that part however it is possible to check that too I'll add an update

Comment: I tried it with my + too and it still matches patterns like 1...23, 1.2.3, and 123..

Comment: Didn't work. How does that differ from my original expression in terms of what it will match since I'm bounding things by the start and end of the line?

Comment: Normally I would agree with your but there are implemtations which ignore that rule. Or better interpret it in another way. At the moment I have no idea how to fix it. I'll make an update if I get an idea.

Comment: If `$` doesn't work, you could append `\n` to the end of the string, then use regex `@"^\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?\n"` on the extended string.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This regex will find valid positive real numbers with or without a decimal point. like `123`, `.123`, `1.123`. The expression can be applied against a string where each value tested is on it's own line or find numbers in the middle of a block of text. It will also allow punctuation like periods and commas directly after the number but won't capture them.

`(?<=^|\s)\d*\.?\d+(?=[,.;]?(?:\s|$))`

[image]

Given Input String:

```
1.2.3
1..2..3
128...
1234
.123
1.123
1...23
1.2.3
123...
I like kittens 345.23, and version 2.3.4 dogs
```

Matches are:

```
1234
.123
1.123
345.23
```

Comment: Random question, how did you generate that pretty chart?

Comment: Hey Matt, I'm using debuggex.com. Although it doesn't support lookbehinds or atomic groups it's still handy for understanding the expression flow. There is also regexper.com. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`@"^\\d*\\.?\\d+$"`

Here it is without escaped backslashes:

`^\d*\.?\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that rekire is right about the `$` symbol not working. If that's the case, then the regex does actually match the empty substring at the start of the string, which explains why it says it's found a match of length 0 at location 0, instead of NSNotFound.

Answer (score 0):

This is REGEX match your strings:

```
[0-9]*(.){0,1}[0-9]+
```